# Bash read -e -i "Test" needs to be in Zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, compatibility

What is zsh equivalent for :

```
read -e -i "This is pre written text " t
```

get user into readline with a pre written text ready to edit an save
to a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this approach:

```
t="This is pre written text "
vared t
```

This will prepopulate the variable `t` and then interactively edit it with zsh's line editor as described in `man zshzle` -- see there also for its command parameters:

> vared [...] *name*
>
> The value of the parameter *name* is loaded into the edit buffer, and the line editor is invoked.  When the  editor
> exits,  name is set to the string value returned by the editor.

Comment: This question was also asked on the zsh mailing list and received a similar answer to mine (even before the question was posted here). I wasn't aware of this answer until now (45 min. later) but for reference here are the links: https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2023/msg00519.html; https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2023/msg00525.html